# Linux GLFW - Vulkan Surface not creating: glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CLIENT_API, GLFW_NO_API) is being ignored?

Tags: c++, linux, glfw, vulkan

I'm having an issue with creating a Vulkan surface for a GLFW Window in Linux. Obviously you need to create a window without a client API. But somehow GLFW ignores that window hint?

GLFW spits out the following error message:

```
GLFW Error 65540: Vulkan: Window surface creation requires the window to have the client API set to GLFW_NO_API
```

I have no clue why this is not working, it seems like GLFW itself is broken.
N.B. the function glfwWindowShouldClose() also seems to ignore close events? Had to make a small workaround.

This is the complete program:

```
#include <vulkan/vulkan.h>

#include <iostream>
#include <stdexcept>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <vector>
#include <cstring>

#define GLFW_INCLUDE_VULKAN
#include <GLFW/glfw3.h>


const uint32_t WINDOW_WIDTH = 1024;
const uint32_t WINDOW_HEIGHT = 768;

// NOTE: somehow GLFW's glfwWindowShouldClose() never returns true?!
// So, we create this global for intended behaviour.
bool RUNNING = false;

std::vector<const char*> validation_layers = {
    "VK_LAYER_KHRONOS_validation"
};

#if NDEBUG
    const bool enable_validation_layers = false;
#else
    const bool enable_validation_layers = true;
#endif

struct Application {
    GLFWwindow *window;

    VkInstance vk_instance;
    VkPhysicalDevice vk_physical_device = VK_NULL_HANDLE;
    VkDevice vk_device;
    VkQueue vk_graphics_queue;
    VkSurfaceKHR vk_surface;
};


void glfwErrorCallback(int code, const char* description) {
    std::cerr << "GLFW Error " << code << ": " << description << std::endl;
}

bool checkValidationLayerSupport() {
    uint32_t count;
    vkEnumerateInstanceLayerProperties(&count, nullptr);

    std::vector<VkLayerProperties> available_layers(count);
    vkEnumerateInstanceLayerProperties(&count, available_layers.data());

    for (const auto &layer_name : validation_layers) {
        bool found = false;

        for (const auto &layer_properties : available_layers) {
            if (strcmp(layer_name, layer_properties.layerName)) {
                found = true;
                break;
            }
        }

        if (!found) return false;
    }

    return true;
}


void windowCloseCallback(GLFWwindow *window) {
    RUNNING = false;
}

void keyCallback(GLFWwindow *window, int key, int scancode, int action, int mods) {
    // nothing
}



static void createVKInstance(VkInstance *instance) {

    if ( enable_validation_layers && !checkValidationLayerSupport() ) {
        throw std::runtime_error("Validation layer requested, but not available!");
    }

    VkApplicationInfo app_info = {};
    app_info.sType = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_APPLICATION_INFO;
    app_info.pApplicationName = "Hello Sailor!";
    app_info.applicationVersion = VK_MAKE_VERSION(1, 0, 0);
    app_info.pEngineName = " No engine";
    app_info.engineVersion = VK_MAKE_VERSION(1, 0 ,0);
    app_info.apiVersion = VK_API_VERSION_1_0;

    VkInstanceCreateInfo create_info = {};
    create_info.sType = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_INSTANCE_CREATE_INFO;
    create_info.pApplicationInfo = &app_info;

    uint32_t glfw_extension_count = 0;
    const char **glfw_extensions;

    glfw_extensions = glfwGetRequiredInstanceExtensions(&glfw_extension_count);

    create_info.enabledExtensionCount = glfw_extension_count;
    create_info.ppEnabledExtensionNames = glfw_extensions;

    if (enable_validation_layers) {
        create_info.enabledLayerCount = (uint32_t) validation_layers.size();
        create_info.ppEnabledLayerNames = validation_layers.data();
    }
    else {
        create_info.enabledLayerCount = 0;
    }

    auto result = vkCreateInstance(&create_info, nullptr, instance);
    if (result != VK_SUCCESS) {
        throw std::runtime_error(" Failed to create Vulkan instance!\n");
    }

    #if 0
        uint32_t p_count = 0;
        vkEnumerateInstanceExtensionProperties(nullptr, &p_count, nullptr);
        std::vector<VkExtensionProperties> props(p_count);
        vkEnumerateInstanceExtensionProperties(nullptr, &p_count, props.data());

        for (auto &prop : props) {
            std::cout << prop.extensionName << std::endl;
        }
    #endif
}


#include <optional>
struct QueueFamilyIndices {
    std::optional<uint32_t> graphics_family;
};

static bool isComplete(QueueFamilyIndices *indices) {
    return indices->graphics_family.has_value();
}

static QueueFamilyIndices findQueueFamilies(VkPhysicalDevice device) {
    QueueFamilyIndices indices;

    uint32_t count = 0;
    vkGetPhysicalDeviceQueueFamilyProperties(device, &count, nullptr);

    std::vector<VkQueueFamilyProperties> queue_families(count);
    vkGetPhysicalDeviceQueueFamilyProperties(device, &count, queue_families.data());

    int i = 0;
    for (const auto &queue_family : queue_families) {
        if (queue_family.queueFlags & VK_QUEUE_GRAPHICS_BIT) {
            indices.graphics_family = i;
        }

        if (isComplete(&indices)) break;

        i++;
    }

    return indices;
}


static bool isDeviceSuitable(VkPhysicalDevice device) {
    QueueFamilyIndices indices = findQueueFamilies(device);

    return isComplete(&indices);
}



static void pickPhysicalDevice(VkInstance instance, VkPhysicalDevice *physical_device) {
    uint32_t count = 0;
    vkEnumeratePhysicalDevices(instance, &count, nullptr);

    if (count == 0) {
        throw std::runtime_error("Failed to find GPUs with Vulkan support!");
    }

    std::vector<VkPhysicalDevice> devices(count);
    vkEnumeratePhysicalDevices(instance, &count, devices.data());

    for (const auto &device : devices) {
        if (isDeviceSuitable(device)) {
            *physical_device = device;
            break;
        }
    }

    if (*physical_device == VK_NULL_HANDLE) {
        throw std::runtime_error("Failed to find suitable GPU!");
    }
}

static void createLogicalDevice(VkPhysicalDevice physical_device, VkDevice *device, VkQueue *graphics_queue) {
    QueueFamilyIndices indices = findQueueFamilies(physical_device);

    if (!isComplete(&indices)) {
        throw std::runtime_error("No queue family indices!");
    }

    VkDeviceQueueCreateInfo create_info = {};
    create_info.sType = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_DEVICE_QUEUE_CREATE_INFO;
    create_info.queueFamilyIndex = indices.graphics_family.value();
    create_info.queueCount = 1;

    float queue_priority = 1.0f;
    create_info.pQueuePriorities = &queue_priority;


    VkPhysicalDeviceFeatures features = {};

    VkDeviceCreateInfo device_create_info = {};
    device_create_info.sType = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_DEVICE_CREATE_INFO;
    device_create_info.pQueueCreateInfos = &create_info;
    device_create_info.queueCreateInfoCount = 1;

    device_create_info.pEnabledFeatures = &features;

    device_create_info.enabledExtensionCount = 0;

    if (enable_validation_layers) {
        device_create_info.enabledLayerCount = (uint32_t) validation_layers.size();
        device_create_info.ppEnabledLayerNames = validation_layers.data();
    }
    else {
        device_create_info.enabledLayerCount = 0;
    }

    if (vkCreateDevice(physical_device, &device_create_info, nullptr, device) != VK_SUCCESS) {
        throw std::runtime_error("Failed to create logical device!");
    }
    vkGetDeviceQueue(*device, indices.graphics_family.value(), 0, graphics_queue);
}

static void createSurface(GLFWwindow *window, VkInstance instance, VkSurfaceKHR *surface) {
    auto result = glfwCreateWindowSurface(instance, window, nullptr, surface);
    if (result != VK_SUCCESS) {
        throw std::runtime_error("Failed to create window surface!");
    }
}

static void initVulkan(/*GLFWwindow *window, VkInstance *instance, VkPhysicalDevice *physical_device, VkDevice *device, VkQueue *graphics_queue, VkSurfaceKHR *surface */
    Application *app
) {
    createVKInstance(&app->vk_instance);
    createSurface(app->window, app->vk_instance, &app->vk_surface);
    pickPhysicalDevice(app->vk_instance, &app->vk_physical_device);
    createLogicalDevice(app->vk_physical_device, &app->vk_device, &app->vk_graphics_queue);
}


static void initWindow(GLFWwindow *window) {
    glfwInit();
    

    glfwSetErrorCallback(glfwErrorCallback);

    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_RESIZABLE, GLFW_FALSE);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CLIENT_API, GLFW_NO_API);

    window = glfwCreateWindow(WINDOW_WIDTH, WINDOW_HEIGHT, "Vulkan", nullptr, nullptr);
    if (window == NULL) {
        throw std::runtime_error("Failed to create window!\n");
    }
    else {
        printf("Created window.\n");
    }

    glfwSetWindowCloseCallback(window, windowCloseCallback);
    glfwSetKeyCallback(window, keyCallback);

    RUNNING = true;
}


static void mainLoop(GLFWwindow *window) {
    while (RUNNING) {
        glfwPollEvents();
    }
}

static void cleanUp(GLFWwindow *window, VkInstance instance, VkDevice device, VkSurfaceKHR surface) {
    printf("Cleaning up!\n");

    glfwDestroyWindow(window);
    glfwTerminate();
    
    vkDestroySurfaceKHR(instance, surface, nullptr);
    vkDestroyInstance(instance, nullptr);
    vkDestroyDevice(device, nullptr);
}

static void runApplication(Application *app) {
    initWindow(app->window);
    initVulkan(app);
    mainLoop(app->window);
    cleanUp(app->window, app->vk_instance, app->vk_device, app->vk_surface);
}




int main() {
    Application app;

    try {
        runApplication(&app);
    }
    catch (const std::exception &e) {
        std::cerr << e.what() << std::endl;
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- You fail to store the GLFW Window handle in your `Application` struct, because you pass it by value, not by reference [1]
- `glfwInit` returns error code, which must be checked, and\or callback should be setup before the call.
- `glfwVulkanSupported` should be called.
- You have sequencing error with `RUNNING` variable. It could conceivably be set `true` even if the window was closed.
- You enable layers, but no reporting extension, so no Vulkan problems would be reported

1:

```
struct Application {
    GLFWwindow *window;
};

// passing GLFWwindow* by value (local copy):
static void initWindow(GLFWwindow *window) { 
    // writing to a local GLFWwindow*,
    // which will be destroyed at end of scope
    window = glfwCreateWindow(/*snip*/);
}

// passing GLFWwindow* by value, not reference:
initWindow(app->window);

// reading\dereferencing uninitialized variable app->window:
createSurface(app->window, app->vk_instance, &app->vk_surface);
```

Comment: "You fail to store the GLFW Window handle in your Application struct, because you pass it by value, not by reference" 
-where?

Comment: @Mr.Vermeer Added to the answer

Comment: So, I never fully realized that pointers were copied when passed by value somehow. Which actually makes sense, just never figured it to be like that.

Comment: @Mr.Vermeer `T` means copy, `T&` means reference. Mistake also avoidable by coding style adjustments. `initWindow` produces that window, so it could return it, rather than pass it as parameter. Additionally the "essential type" for GLFW is the pointer itself rather than the pointee (and the pointee is opaque anyway I think for the API users), so wrapping that pointer into a `typedef` would further help reduce human errors. Being consistent with reference types would help. Take const reference for reading, non-const reference for writing, and non-reference when you want local writeable copy.